# Bad render of smooth surfaces (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a blend file where smooth surfaces are somehow rendered in a terrible way (full of black spots, rough edges, bad reflection.. the works).

- If I export the object (fbx) and import into a new .blend file, everything is fine
- In non-render modes (Solid / Material mode) everything looks butter smooth

So the issue seems not to be with the object, but rather with the render / other blender settings - but I can not fine anything wrong!

Any help is greatly appreciated :).

You can find the file <[image]>.

Warner

[image: render]

Comment: Downloaded the file, but everything seems to render fine. I am not getting the black artifacts in your screenshot.

Comment: Trying a bit further, I'm only getting them when opening the file and setting the viewport to 'rendered'. It seems with F12 (camera render) everything goes fine.

Also that way you don't have any issue?

Comment: This above is exactly what happens to me... how to get rid? I don't know, atm.

Comment: The object is relatively too small, imho. Try (just a test) to scale it up 20x and see what happens in viewport... ;)

Comment: Scaling doesn't seem to have any effect.. However, "re-setting" the viewport with ctrl-0 (set view on selected object) seems to somehow resolve the issue. Not sure why - perhaps a bug?

Comment: @Warner in my test scale 20x "worked", perhaps because the object size it is related to the clipping settings explained in the answer below... I guess that for a "sink" object 50km is pretty too much, even 500m...

Answer (score 1):

Change the end clip view parameter (N Panel) to something smaller.
before :[image: bad clip]
after :[image: good clip]

Comment: Thanks Bithur! Though, it seems your solution has the same effect as the "re-set" of the viewport with ctrl-0.. the 50km value doesn't seem to be the underlying symptom.

Comment: Your problem only occurs in ortho view, not in perspective. Ctrl+0 uses the selected object as camera (no reset), changing the view to perspective and making the problem disapear. If you get out of camera view (Numpad 0) and go back in ortho view (Numpad 5) the problem will come back unless you change the end clip.